# Frozen Video Feed

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, peerjs

I build a simple video chat app using WebRTC via PeerJS with React.

Everything seems to be working accept the video feed is frozen unless the Chrome tab with that video is selected and the user is clicking/scrolling/entering text from the keyboard. ie it seems that the video feed doesn't re-render unless the user is continuously sending events from the client. Obviously this is not the desired behavior; it should stream audio/video whether the user has selected that tab or not and whether they are scrolling or not.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Peer from 'peerjs';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const peer = new Peer({key: 'lwjd5qra8257b9'});
        console.log('peer', peer);
        peer.on('open', (id) => {
            //this.setState({ peer, id })
            this.setState({ id })
            this.peer = peer;
        });
        // ANSWER
        peer.on('call', async (call) => {
            const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
            call.answer(localStream);
            call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
                this.setState({url: URL.createObjectURL(remoteStream)});
            });
        });
    }
    call = async (id) => {
        const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
        //const call = this.state.peer.call(id, localStream);
        const call = this.peer.call(id, localStream);
        call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
            this.setState({url: URL.createObjectURL(remoteStream)});
        });
    } 
    submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const idInp = e.currentTarget.querySelector('.id');
        const id = idInp.value;
        idInp.value = '';
        this.call(id);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h2 className="myId">{ this.state.id || '' }</h2>
                </header>
                <form className="callForm" onSubmit={ this.submitForm }>
                    <input className="id" type="text" name='id' />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                { this.state.url && <video autoplay src={this.state.url} /> }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This vaguely sounds like an issue with autoplay policies. This should only happen in Chrome Beta and Canary though. Does this happen if you start Chrome with --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=804091#c13)

You might also want to get rid of URL.createObjectURL (which is deprecated in Chrome as well now) and set the video srcObject to the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Issue was that I was using `autoplay` instead of `autoPlay`. Very finicky...

Comment: That may be the case. However when I set it to `autoPlay` it works and when I set it to `autoplay` it does not work.

Comment: It did still happen when I launched chrome with `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the `autoplay` attribute on the `video` element to `autoPlay`.